# How to get query of users in Laravel with where condition

Tags: php, laravel, roles

I have a table for `users` and in that table, I have the column `user_type_id` which is related to another table called `user_types`. There are specific roles(subscriber and admin). Now, In my controller, I want to get all users with the condition that their user_type_id is equal to 2. With this way of doing it, I am getting only the first row...

My Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $subscriber = User::where('user_type_id', 2)->firstOrFail();
    return view('show_subscriber', compact('subscriber'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function show($id) {
    $subscriber = User::where('user_type_id', 2)->get();
    return view('show_subscriber', compact('subscriber'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($id) {
    $subscriber = User::where('user_type_id', 2)->firstOrFail();
    return view('show_subscriber', compact('subscriber'));
}
```

firstOrFail() will return the first matching record and if no matching record is found it will simply return 404- resource not found.

```
public function show($id) {
    $subscriber = User::where('user_type_id', 2)->get();
    return view('show_subscriber', compact('subscriber'));
}
```

get() will return all the matching records as a collection.

see details here [https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions](https://firstOrFail()).

[https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#collections](https://get())

Comment: your initial query was you were not getting all the users based on the conditions. And if you are having problem in your blade file you need to share that code portion in order to get help

Comment: I am getting: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.